# Maven beans.xml

Tags: java, maven, weld

Im using maven and weld. I have created beans.xml but while im starting app (java application) i have error like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBFdw.png)

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.kamczi</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-di</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000016: Missing beans.xml file in META-INF
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:539)
    at com.kamczi.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: Please post your error, not an image of it.

Comment: Where do you have the `beans.xml` file in your build environment?

Comment: Okey, i placed src/test/resources instead of src/main/resources, solved

Comment: Can you please upgrade your maven-compiler-plugin version to 3.8.0 cause the 3.0 is about ..6 years old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the problem here is that you have your `beans.xml` under `src/test/...` while Weld presumes there is one in `src/main/...`.

If it is testing you are after, then I suggest you either use a synthetic bean archive in case you are in SE or, if in EE, then you can leverage Shrinkwrap and Arquillian to create a deployment with whatever `beans.xml` you want.